How to send a Google Doc as an attachment in the OpenAI API prompt and ask questions about it?
I'm currently working on a project using the OpenAI API, and I want to know if it's possible to send a Google Doc as an attachment in the prompt and then ask questions about its content directly.
For example, I have a Google Doc with several paragraphs and I want to include it in the OpenAI prompt so that I can query the content within it, like summarizing specific sections or retrieving certain information.
Question:
Is there a way to attach a Google Doc file directly to the OpenAI API prompt?
Are there any best practices or limitations to keep in mind when working with external document content in the OpenAI API?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
